# Redirect to new Mongo Saved ID after Express POST?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my POST request, I'm saving a new document into my mongo database. After the database is saved, can I do a res.redirect to that exact document ID?? I'm unsure of how to do this. I can't find any tutorials, documentation, or stackoverflow questions that seem to answer exactly what I'm looking for.

Can I do something like this? Where the :id is the Id of the document I just saved in mongoose/mongo?

newItem.save().then(res.redirect('/results/:id');

I expect the user to submit a post request. I'm saving the information into a mongo document through mongoose. Then after saving it I'd like to redirect to a new URL with the ID of the saved item on that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can.

The [`save()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) method can accept a callback so you can get the `_id` field of the saved document.

One way of do it would be:

```
newItem.save((err, itemSaved) => {
    if(err) {
        next(err);
    }
    const itemId = itemSaved._id;
    res.redirect('/results/' + itemId);
});
```

Hopefully, this will solve your problem.

**P.S.**

There's no need to use a colon on redirect's path. Beware with that, 'cause using it will give you a `Cast Error`.

Comment: Alright thanks a ton! I'll try it tonight! Greatly appreciate your response!